# Taranis x9d plus se 2019 malfunctioning

Tags: taranis

My taranis suddenly stopped working properly. When I turn on the taranis it does not read my crossfire module anymore (sometimes the crossfire turns on/off randomly) and then the taranis screen goes blank.

The taranis is still on when the screen goes blank. I've replaced the internal 3v battery and the issue still continues.

I've also made sure my connections are connected properly.

What is the best way to troubleshoot this?

Where can I buy spare parts such as a backboard or front board for the taranis, cannot find a vendor in the US.

Comment: Have you tried removing the Crossfire module to see if the issue is with the X9D or the Crossfire JR module?

Comment: Yes I removed the crossfire module and the issue persist, though it does take longer for the taranis to go blank. Also the blue light does not light up on the taranis.

Comment: @ipconfig Also, sometimes when the screen goes out, the taranis goes out. When I try to turn it on nothing happens. I have to disconnect ans reconnect the main battery and then the taranis turns on, as if something short-circuits.

Comment: Huh, that's quite odd. Sounds like a hardware issue, you might want to RMA it to FrSky.

Comment: I shall do that. Thank you for the help @ifconfig, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> Sounds like a hardware issue, you might want to RMA it to FrSky.

The best way to get advice for troubleshooting and replacement parts is directly from FrSky.